# How to redirect users using HTTP response

Tags: java, struts

I have a scenario where the user clicks on a 'restaurant' link (for searching restaurants in a particular locality). I have to check whether the location is set or not. If it is not set, I want to redirect him to a page that allows him to set the location, and, then, go back to search results filtered by the set location. I'm using `response.sendRedirect(url)` to redirect the user to the setting location page. But, how can I send the redirect back URL (i.e., the URL where I want to send the user after the location is set)?

I tried this:

```
response.sendRedirect("/location/set.html?action=asklocation&redirectUrl="+
            request.getRequestUri()+request.getQueryString());
```

but this isn't working and 404 error is shown; also, the url formed in the browser doesn't look good.

Please, if anyone could solve the problem ...

Comment: Error 404 FileNotFound, you need to ensure that http://<WebAppName>/location/set.html exists. What happens when you fire the url mentioned?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you're missing at least a "?" between `request.getRequestUri()` and `request.getQueryString()`. You should url-encode the parameter as well, which you can use `java.net.URLEncoder` for.

Also, when doing redirects you need to prepend the context path: `request.getContextPath()`.

Something like

```
String secondRedirectUrl = request.getRequestUri()+"?"+request.getQueryString(); 
String encodedSecondRedirectUrl = URLEncoder.encode(secondRedirectUrl, serverUrlEncodingPreferablyUTF8);
String firstRedirectUrl = request.getContextPath()+"/location/set.html?action=asklocation&redirectUrl="+encodedSecondRedirectUrl;
response.sendRedirect(firstRedirectUrl);
```

Personally, i'd rather solve the problem by storing a `RequestDispatcher` in the session and forwarding to it after the location has been set.

Comment: Why does he need the additional `?`, the OP included it in his relative url

Comment: The value of the `redirectUrl` parameter is a path with query string that the OP wants to redirect to after setting the location on `/location/set.html`. He needs to separate the path from the query string. Otherwise if the current page is `/foo/bar?problem=lol`, he will end up at `/foo/barproblem=lol`, which gives 404.

Comment: The url `location/set.html?action=asklocation&redirectUrl=` already contains a `?`, do you meant to say `&`?

Comment: Read what i wrote again. The value of the parameter `redirectUrl` is a *separate* path with query string (the path and query string of the current page) from `/location/set.html`, which he wants to redirect to *after* having been redirected and set the location at `/location/set.html`. In fact, that he is nesting a path+query string in another path+query string is the reason he needs to url-encode the nested path+query string.

Comment: Thanks I've got it working. I've encoded the url and now it's working.

Answer (score 1):

My first response will be to remove the `/` on your URL, something of this effect (to your code):

```
response.sendRedirect("location/set.html?action=asklocation&redirectUrl="+
            request.getRequestUri()+request.getQueryString());
```

If that doesn't work, add `request.getContextPath()` at the beginning of your url string, like so:

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/location/set.html?action=asklocation&redirectUrl="+request.getRequestUri()+request.getQueryString());
```

The [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) states:

> If the location is relative without a
>   leading '/' the container interprets
>   it as relative to the current request
>   URI. If the location is relative with
>   a leading '/' the container interprets
>   it as relative to the servlet
>   container root.

Comment: The op never states that the path is relative to the current request URI?

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström, nope..but since he's getting a 404, The Servlet container fails to map it to the full URL.

Comment: I understood it to mean that the 404 was when trying to redirect to the path provided in the parameter. Also, the 404 might be because he is missing the context path.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström, it could be.